# When Django Form is Invalid, why only file type input is rest?

Tags: html, django, forms, validation, input

If there is an invalid field after submitting my Django Form, the other fields have input values when submitted, but only the inputs of the file type will be emptied. I don't think there's anything to change in Dajngo. Perhaps this is a characteristic of html file type input?

For example, my form compresses video files uploaded by users. And it takes quite a bit of time. If something goes wrong after submitting the form, the user must select the file again and proceed with the compression process. This is not good.

Forms.py

```
class VideoArtUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.VideoArt
        fields = (
            "video",
            "thumbnail",
            "poster",
            "title",
            "year",
            "artist",
            "description",
        )
        widgets = {
            "video": forms.FileInput(attrs={"accept": "video/mp4"}),
            "title": forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Il titolo del video"}),
            "year": forms.TextInput(
                attrs={"placeholder": "l'anno in cui il video è uscito"}
            ),
            "artist": forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Il nome di artista"}),
            "description": forms.Textarea(
                attrs={"placeholder": "una descrizione del video "}
            ),
        }

    def clean_thumbnail(self):
        thumbnail = self.cleaned_data.get('thumbnail')
        if thumbnail:
            if thumbnail.size > 10*1024*1024:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Thumnail si deve essere meno di 10MB")
            return thumbnail
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Thumnail è necessario")

    def clean_poster(self):
        poster = self.cleaned_data.get('poster')
        if poster and (type(poster) != str):
            if poster.size > 10*1024*1024:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Cover image si deve essere meno di 10MB")
            return poster
    
    def clean_video(self):
        video = self.cleaned_data.get("video")
        if video and (type(video) != str):
            if video.size > 1000*1024*1024:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Il video si deve essre meno di 1GB")
            return video


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        videoart = super().save(commit=False)
        video = self.cleaned_data.get("video")
        video_path = video.temporary_file_path()
        get_duration =  subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe', '-i', f'{video_path}', '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-v', 'quiet', '-of', 'csv=%s' % ("p=0")])
        duration = int(float(get_duration.decode('utf-8').replace("\n", ""))) 
        videoart.duration = duration    
        return videoart
```

Views.py

```
class VideoArtUpload(user_mixins.MoiveUploadPermissionView, FormView):

    """VideoartUpload View Definition"""

    form_class = forms.VideoArtUploadForm
    template_name = "videoarts/videoart_upload.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        videoart = form.save()
        videoart.user = self.request.user
        videoart.save()
        return redirect(reverse("videoarts:detail", kwargs={"pk": videoart.pk}))
```

Upload template - form

```
<form id="upload_video_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
                {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                     {% include "../mixins/nonefield_error.html" %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            <div class="upload_form__sections">
                <div class="video-section">
                    {% for field in form %}
                            <div class="upload_form_field">
                                <div class="upload_form_label">{{field.label}}</div>
                                {{field}}
                                {% if field.errors %}
                                {% for error in field.errors %}
                                    {% include "../mixins/field_error.html" %}
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <div class="upload_submit">
                        <button>Carica</button>
                        <div id="progress" hidden>
                            <span id="progress_bar"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>            
        </form>
```

Comment: Can you add error message in your question ?

Comment: @Ahtisham Hello, Actually, there is no error message. I asked about a situation. So the user submits the form with input type=file but if the form is invalid (for validation error) and the user will see the new form with values previous. but the value of the input(type=file) is gone. I wanna know why and the solution if there is somthing one.

Comment: If because of validation the file has to be processed again then that is not an issue. You can make expensive task to run in background using celery and show user the file is being processed in the meantime the user can interact with the UI and once processing is done inform the user.